# Apache Drill SQL: Division fails when numerator > denominator

Tags: sql, apache-drill

I am facing this strange but basic problem with apache-drill SQL, a simple division by operation is giving wrong result as shown below:

```
0: jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost> SELECT 'Test' FROM (VALUES(1));
+---------+
| EXPR$0  |
+---------+
| Test    |
+---------+
1 row selected (1.027 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost> select 10/100 from (VALUES(1));
+---------+
| EXPR$0  |
+---------+
| 0       |
+---------+
1 row selected (0.67 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost> select 100/10 from (VALUES(1));
+---------+
| EXPR$0  |
+---------+
| 10      |
+---------+
1 row selected (0.662 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost> select 10/11 from (VALUES(1));
+---------+
| EXPR$0  |
+---------+
| 0       |
+---------+
1 row selected (0.649 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost> select cast(10/11 as float) from (VALUES(1));
+---------+
| EXPR$0  |
+---------+
| 0.0     |
+---------+
1 row selected (0.74 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost> select cast(10/11 as double) from (VALUES(1));
+---------+
| EXPR$0  |
+---------+
| 0.0     |
+---------+
1 row selected (0.691 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost> select cast(10*100/11 as double) from (VALUES(1));
+---------+
| EXPR$0  |
+---------+
| 90.0    |
+---------+
1 row selected (0.72 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost> select cast(10*100/11 as double)/100 from (VALUES(1));
+---------+
| EXPR$0  |
+---------+
| 0.9     |
+---------+
```

Drill version is 1.6 and 1.8 (tried in both). Even `round` is not helping. Is there any work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is integer arithmetic.
11/4 = 2 (and reminder = 3)

You have to convert one of the values to the requested type.

```
select cast(x as float)/y
```